# Populating a tableview with strings which are the second element [1] in arrays which are nested into NSDictionary plist

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ipad, uitableview, plist

I am working on a project for iPad using storyboard.
I am trying to populate my UITableView with data from a plist. The Plist has an NSDictionary, which in turn has 9 Arrays, each with three elements (one number and two strings). I want to take the second element [1] from each array (which is a string) and populate the table with those strings.

From header file;

```
@interface EonOrderOfPrinciple : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *formManeuvers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *Wild;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Smash;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *CloseCombat;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *HeadButt;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Pummel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Obstacle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Confusion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *ImpWeap;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Rage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *WildStorm;
```

From implementation;

```
NSString *aFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                        pathForResource:@"Wild" ofType:@"plist"];
Wild = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aFile];

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

NSString *currentManeuverName;
currentManeuverName = [Smash objectAtIndex:1];
[[cell textLabel] setText:currentManeuverName];
return cell;
}
@end
```

I realize I am only giving it one cell right now. I figured once I get one to work, I can then try to get the rest to populate. Right now I cannot even get that one.

None of the tutorials, nor help I have found, has explained how to use nested data like this. I have tried to use various versions of things I have found, but nothing works.
I wanted to learn how to use plists before I move onto Core Data. Very simple plists I have made work fine, it seems to be this nested business that is tripping me up.

*** update Oct 29 ... I have now removed the plist ***

SO. How, with a nested dictionary plist, do you access the information correctly, and populate the table. Again, this is using the nested dictionaries. This is what I do not know how to do, and this is what I am trying to learn how to do.

Comment: I did @synthesize for Wild and Smash

Comment: Can you update the question with the plist content?

Comment: Not related to your question, but why do you alloc another cell after reusing the cell with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?

Comment: Is `currentManeuverName` nil?

Comment: I think what you're completely missing is setting up a proper data source.

Comment: the "NSString *currentManeuverName;" part is an attempt to make the function reusable. I will end up having 12 dictionaries, that "Wild" is just one of ... my hopes were to end up having to only call one function to populate a table. With all the trouble this one is giving me, I heavily narrowed and focused so I could hopefully make it work.

Comment: HAS, you are on to something. My problem is not know how to use the nested plists properly, neilco had caused me to try something, that worked. Wild is simply a Dictionary nested into a Dictionary named Maneuvers. I guess what I needed is to figure out how to access the nested Dictionary. Clearly there is another way to do this that I am unaware of. So, it ends up the plist posted and explanation were not exactly accurate, I am sorry to all for my ignorance. I will update my plist to be fully accurate.

Comment: it feels like your question is asking for a code solution when it would be better for you to dig in and practice with plists and ask a more specific question if needed. There are more ways than one to do what you're asking(like using table sections or copying the array to a table array property, etc)

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER WITH THE PLIST IN THE QUESTION :**

I think you need to have more reflection about how you build your PLIST.

In your case, I think it's better to do something like this :

**Wild.plist**

```
// Choose your key

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Smash</string>
        <key>letter</key>
        <string>F</string>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Close Combat</string>
        <key>letter</key>
        <string>W</string>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>2</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

**in your .h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

**in your .m :**

```
// Your keys depend of your PLIST
#define KEY_TITLE @"title"
#define KEY_LETTER @"letter"
#define KEY_ID @"id"

// Data from your plist
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *data

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wild" ofType:@"plist"]];

    self.data = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in a)
        [data addObject:[dic objectForKey:KEY_TITLE]; // Define your key
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**OLD ANSWER BEFORE PLIST :**

You need to get all the second elements of your PLIST file in a new mutable array, and you declare this like a `@property`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *data
```

in your viewDidLoad build this array :

(I consider your PLIST with an array for first key, add your PLIST please for more information).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wild" ofType:@"plist"]];

    self.data = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in a)
        [data addObject:[dic objectForKey:KEY_SECOND_ELEMENT]]; // KEY_SECOND_ELEMENT is the key on your plist
}
```

next for your table view :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: xcode seems to not like KEY_SECOND_ELEMENT ... it also didn't like "cell.textLabel = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" so I changed it to "[[cell textLabel] setText:[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];" which it likes.

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'KEY_SECOND_ELEMENT'

Comment: Of course, KEY_SECOND_ELEMENT is your key on your PLIST, I edit my answer

Comment: @interface EonOrderOfPrinciple : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> was already in my header, I will update my header to reflect this, sorry.

Comment: You want my plist to be an array of dictionaries? each maneuver being its own dictionary? ...

Comment: Yes I think it´s a better solution. Did you try my second answer ?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to make your plist. I am not writing in native xml, I am using xcode and its Property List file to make it.

Comment: just go to XCode > your plist file > right click > open as source code > copy past my plist and fill it with your own values

Comment: If I were to copy paste your plist, then I would still not know how to do this on my own.

Comment: If you use my plist and my code it's work. You need to adapt your plist it's not difficult

Comment: This is the right answer, in my opinion, but I will post another version, and upvote yours.

Comment: Thanks. However, I suggest you to use Core Data instead of plist file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load the plist into a dictionary and extract the arrays from it:

```
NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wild" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *Wild = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];

self.Smash = [Wild objectForKey:@"Smash"];
self.CloseCombat = [Wild objectForKey:@"CloseCombat"];
self.HeadButt = [Wild objectForKey:@"HeadButt"];
.
.
.
```

Then you need to associate that data with the UITableViewCell:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSString *currentManeuverName;
    currentManeuverName = [Smash objectAtIndex:1];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:currentManeuverName];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: this tells me (with some NSLogging) that there is no string being passed into currentManeuverName ... even just NSLogging [Smash objectAtIndex:1] returns (null). It appears that we are still not getting that string from the plist.

Comment: I built a new plist, with Wild as Root (dictionary) and only the Smash array, and this code works with that. If Wild is a dictionary that were to be nested into another Dictionary Lets say plist root Maneuvers (a dictionary) ... how would I access that?

Comment: I have updated the plist with ALL the info it has, most is unneeded at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to load your plist in sections and rows with parent keys as section headers! Here is how you can do just that in 3 easy steps.

**Step 1:** First of all you do not need a lot of properties just to hold parent keys. Just add two class level variables as below:

```
@interface EonOrderOfPrinciple () {
    NSDictionary    *parentDict;
    NSArray         *parentKeys;
}
```

**Step 2:** Populate these class level variables in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *aFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wild" ofType:@"plist"];

    parentDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:aFile];
    parentKeys = [parentDict allKeys];

    [self.formManeuvers reloadData];
}
```

**Step 3:** Then load them in your table data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return parentKeys.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return parentKeys[section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *parentKey     = parentKeys[section];
    NSDictionary *childDict = parentDict[parentKey];

    return [childDict allKeys].count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell           = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *parentKey     = parentKeys[indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary *childDict = parentDict[parentKey];
    NSArray *childKeys      = [childDict allKeys];

    NSString *childKey   = childKeys[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text  = childDict[childKey][1];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yas, you may need to explain what Parent Keys are, if he knew how to use bridge tables and foreign keys, I'm sure he wouldn't be asking this question! Good solution regardless!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're loading the data just fine, if you somewhere do
`Smash = (NSArray*)[Wild objectForKey:@"WhateverKeyIsForWild"];`
before accessing.

I don't think your problem is nested dictionaries or PLists or anything, since you've gotten it to work here and there. (I'm going by the comments, not by any other message boards).

I believe what's getting you is iOS. Does your loading function happen before you access the array? Try testing to see if Smash is loaded with data by logging its contents when it accesses the data.

```
NSLog(@"%@", Smash); // should automatically dump its contents into the logger
```

If there's nothing, nil, garbage, unexpected data, then you'll have to follow your code and ensure that the loading happens first, or memory isn't garbage collected.

Try disabling ARC, you can copy and paste your code into a new project that doesn't have it. Since nothing will change (because it's ok to leak if you're just testing a few strings). If it works, you know ARC is it.

The lifecycle of a table is interesting, and somewhat annoying, in that you only have a few things you can count on regarding order of operations.

Well, this answer is much longer than I wanted it to be, I apologize for that. Blame ARC.

Comment: Also, please communicate about this problem here, except for light comments ;) The record will help you later.